# Electron-vite preview showing blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, electron, vite

I made a electron-vite (https://evite.netlify.app/) react project and when I run preview, it gives me a blank screen, although build is successful.

I tried getting the renderer content (index.html, assets ...) in 'out' folder and putting it in a normal vite react project, so when I run vite preview, it shows me the project I'd built in electron-vite. It worked. Can't get my head around why electron-vite preview is not working.

**Electron-vite Project**

[electron-vite preview with devTools source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CpN7.png)

[react-vite preview with devTools source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSnEg.png)

[electron main.js loadFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMw7u.png)

Comment: I solved it by changing BrowserRouter to HashRouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shuld use hashRouter instead of browserRouter.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```